# adding text to end of label and including a <br> tag not working well

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make the label inside my pie chart appear on 2 lines and it does not work:

```
<PieChart
        data={[{
          title: 'One',
          value: 82,
          color: '#007DCD'
        }]}
        totalValue={100}
        lineWidth={20}
        label={({ data, dataIndex }) =>
        Math.round(data[dataIndex].percentage) + '% ' + <br/> + 'complete'
      }
        labelStyle={{
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontFamily: 'Lato'
        }}
      />
```

Comment: *does not work*  Meaning what exactly?  Using developer console, can you see the insertion of the `<br>` tag?

Comment: In the console it looks like this - 82% [object Object]complete

Answer (score 1):

React will try to protect you from [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) or from accidentally inserting unintentional DOM elements into the output by escaping strings such as `foo < bar` to `foo &lt; bar`. To get around this, try using a [`Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
<PieChart
    data={[{
      title: 'One',
      value: 82,
      color: '#007DCD'
    }]}
    totalValue={100}
    lineWidth={20}
    label={({ data, dataIndex }) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        {Math.round(data[dataIndex].percentage)}% <br/>complete
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
    labelStyle={{
      fontSize: '12px',
      fontFamily: 'Lato'
    }}
  />
```